How to get highlighted text with Javascript?
So I actually have this mostly working, but I've run into an issue that I can't quite get sorted. First I need to give a quick explanation of what I'm trying to do:
What I'm trying to do and the accompanying code
The page displays a chapter from the Bible. For any verse, I would like to allow the user to either highlight the whole verse by double clicking on it, or they can just highlight a portion of the sentence rather than the whole verse by selecting it with their mouse.
So far, so good. My code allows the user to do both, as intended. Here is the code I have that I am using to do so.
The problem I am encountering
Highlighting a random string with the mouse works fine, HOWEVER, if the user single clicks anywhere on a verse, it inserts the <mark> element in an empty space:
I<mark></mark>n the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.

This is no bueno, obviously. Really, what should be happening is that a string should only be highlighted if it meets the following conditions -

The user actually selects a string
The current verse is not already highlighted (highlighted verses have the "highlight" class added to the parent span tag

I'm hoping one of you S.O. legends can guide me here and tell me what I'm missing in my code above. As always, thank you so much for your help and contributions to the community.
An example of HTML output that displays a verse:


$('.bogus').on('dblclick', function() {
  const {
    book,
    chapter,
    verse
  } = $(this).data();
  highlighter(book, chapter, verse);
});

function highlighter(book, chapter, verse) {
  // Hightlight / remove highlight from verse
  if ($("#" + verse).hasClass('highlight')) {
    $("#" + verse).removeClass('highlight');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{{ base_url }}bible/removeHighlight/",
      data: {
        book: book,
        chapter: chapter,
        verse: verse
      },
      dataType: "json",
      encode: true,
    });
  } else {
    $("#" + verse).addClass('highlight');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{{ base_url }}bible/addHighlight/",
      data: {
        book: book,
        chapter: chapter,
        verse: verse
      },
      dataType: "json",
      encode: true,
    });
  }
}

// For highlighting a portion of a verse that user has selected with mouse:
// Wrap the text that user has selected with '<mark>' element

function markSelection() {
  let selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  let selectedContent = selection.extractContents();
  var mark = document.createElement("mark");
  // mark.style.backgroundColor = "lightpink";
  mark.appendChild(selectedContent);
  selection.insertNode(mark);
}

// Get the text that was highlighted so we can save it to DB

function getSelectionText() {
  var text = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
}

$('.bogus').on("mouseup", function(e) {
  const {
    book,
    chapter,
    verse
  } = $(this).data();

  if ($("#" + verse).hasClass("highlight")) {
    // do nothing
  } else {
    if (getSelectionText() != '' && getSelectionText() != ' ') {
      markSelection();
    }
  }
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="1" class="bogus" data-book="Genesis" data-chapter="1" data-verse="1">
    <sup class="verse">1</sup> 
    <span id="verseText-1">In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth</span>
</span>




If you don't want <mark></mark> check the length of selectedContent before you create the mark.

You forget to return the result of the getSelectionText function!
This is your version. You set the value of text variable. However, this variable does not exists outside of the function.
  function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
      if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
      } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
      }
    }

You need to return the value:
  function getSelectionText() {
      var text = "";
      if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
      } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
      }
    return text; // <-- This line what you missed
    }

And the whole working code:


$('.bogus').on('dblclick', function() {
  const {
    book,
    chapter,
    verse
  } = $(this).data();
  highlighter(book, chapter, verse);
});

function highlighter(book, chapter, verse) {
  // Hightlight / remove highlight from verse
  if ($("#" + verse).hasClass('highlight')) {
    $("#" + verse).removeClass('highlight');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{{ base_url }}bible/removeHighlight/",
      data: {
        book: book,
        chapter: chapter,
        verse: verse
      },
      dataType: "json",
      encode: true,
    });
  } else {
    $("#" + verse).addClass('highlight');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{{ base_url }}bible/addHighlight/",
      data: {
        book: book,
        chapter: chapter,
        verse: verse
      },
      dataType: "json",
      encode: true,
    });
  }
}

// For highlighting a portion of a verse that user has selected with mouse:
// Wrap the text that user has selected with '<mark>' element

function markSelection() {
  let selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  let selectedContent = selection.extractContents();
  var mark = document.createElement("mark");
  // mark.style.backgroundColor = "lightpink";
  mark.appendChild(selectedContent);
  selection.insertNode(mark);
}

// Get the text that was highlighted so we can save it to DB

function getSelectionText() {
  var text = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
return text;
}

$('.bogus').on("mouseup", function(e) {
  const {
    book,
    chapter,
    verse
  } = $(this).data();

  if ($("#" + verse).hasClass("highlight")) {
    // do nothing
  } else {
    if (getSelectionText() != '' && getSelectionText() != ' ') {
      markSelection();
    }
  }
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="1" class="bogus" data-book="Genesis" data-chapter="1" data-verse="1">
    <sup class="verse">1</sup> 
    <span id="verseText-1">In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth</span>
</span>




Wow, in retrospect, that was a silly mistake! Thank you very much for pointing that out. It solves one of the issues, now I just need to sort out the part where it only selects if the "highlight" class is not already applied to the parent span, but I should be able to work that out on my own. Thank you again!
